# Expect a specific instance for mock in Scalamock

Tags: scala, scalamock

Why can I not tell a mock that it should expect an instance of a class without explicitly giving the type? Here is what I mean:

```
val myClass = new MyClass(...)
val traitMock = mock[MyTrait]
(traitMock.mymethod _).expects(myClass).returning(12.3)
```

does not work, while

```
val myClass: MyClass = new MyClass(...)
val traitMock = mock[MyTrait]
(traitMock.mymethod _).expects(myClass).returning(12.3)
```

does work. How come the type can not be inferred?

My testing part in `build.sbt` is

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
    exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect")
    exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml")
)

libraryDependencies += "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.3.0" % "test"
```

Since I was asked for `MyClass` (it is `SpacePoint` here):

```
trait SpacePoint {
  val location: SpaceLocation
}
val sp = new SpacePoint {
  override val location: SpaceLocation = new SpaceLocation(DenseVector(1.0, 1.0))
}
```

Comment: Please specify scalamock and scalatest versions that you are using. Also please provide sources of `MyClass`

Comment: @tkachuko: Does this help?

Comment: let me try to run example locally

Comment: ok, now it is quite unclear how your test looks like (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If `MyClass` is `SpacePoint`, what is  `MyTrait` then? Could you please provide sources of test case involving `SpacePoint`?

Answer (score 1):

So actually it **works for me**. Let me mention that type inference in the code:

```
val myClass = new MyClass(...)
```

has nothing to do with `ScalaMock` but is guaranteed by scala itself. Below I will specify working sample with library versions and sources of the classes.

**Testing libraries:**

```
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test",
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.2.2" % "test"
```

**Source code of classes:**

```
class MyClass(val something: String)

trait MyTrait {

  def mymethod(smth: MyClass): Double
}
```

**Source code of test:**

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class ScalamockTest extends WordSpec with MockFactory with Matchers {

  "ScalaMock" should {

    "infers type" in {
      val myClass = new MyClass("Hello")
      val traitMock = mock[MyTrait]
      (traitMock.mymethod _).expects(myClass).returning(12.3)

      traitMock.mymethod(myClass) shouldBe 12.3
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps. Will be ready to update answer once you provide more details.